# Writing a bluetooth input stream to a file skips data

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream, printwriter

I am trying to write an app that will log the output of an arduino Due to a text file on the phone or tablet. The output rate is 1kHz. I have based my app on the Blueserial code (https://github.com/plastygrove/BlueSerial). The bluetooth connection gets established properly with the arduino bluetooth module, the commands are sent and received properly and everything seems to work just fine. However, the file that I am saving the data to is missing blocks of data, usually around 200ms worth every so often (I have a millisecond timestamp included in my data), resulting in corrupted data. I have been trying to figure out the source of the problem and I think it might be related to the gc but at this point I am at a loss. This is the code that writes my data to the file:

```
private class ReadInput implements Runnable {

    private boolean bStop = false;
    private Thread t;

    public ReadInput() {
        t = new Thread(this, "Input Thread");
        t.start();
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return t.isAlive();
    }

    public void run() {
        InputStream inputStream;

        try {
            inputStream = mBTSocket.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            while (!bStop) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[250];
                int bytes = 0;
                if (bis.available() > 0) {
                    bytes = bis.read(buffer);
                    strInput = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                    sb.append(strInput);
                    int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");                            // determine the end-of-line
                    pw.print(strInput);                                                 // print buffer to the file buffer
                    pw.flush();                                                         // flush buffer and force write to media


                    if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // if end-of-line,
                        String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());                                      // and clear the string
                        pw.print(strInput);                                             // write buffer to file buffer
                        pw.flush();                                                     // force writing to file
                        pw.close();                                                     // close print writer
                        try {
                            f.close();                                                  // close file output stream
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }   
                    sb.delete(0, sb.length()); strInput = "";                                           

                }
                //Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        bStop = true;
    }

}
```

and this is my file outputsteam and printwriter declarations:

```
String strInput = null;
static PrintWriter pw = null;
static FileOutputStream f = null;
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

The data I am sending is formatted as so:

```
24.330,-58,5,119,460\n
24.331,-86,25,-105,460\n
24.332,66,41,-145,460\n
24.333,90,-23,-85,4622,-7,119,460\n
24.524,6,-95,107,461\n
24.525,10,-7,-173,461\n
24.526,-22,33,103,461\n
```

and in this example you can see where it skipped some data. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: You're right Keithrel, I've added the rest of the missing class. In my main activity, there are two other classes, one BtConnect calls `mReadThread = new ReadInput();` kicks off the input reader once the bluetooth communication is established, the other one, BTDisconnect calls `mReadThread.stop();` when the user chose to disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be code missing or you have some extra logic.
For example the StringBuilder doesn't appear to be doing anything,
bStop is never set/cleared.  But you are always printing out the incoming data
via `strInput`.

The end of line handling also looks off, specifically this:

```
String sbprint = sb.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);               // extract string
sb.delete(0, sb.length());
```

You extract the string and then delete the whole buffer `sb.delete(0,sb.length())`
same at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: The intent of my logic was to look for my end of file marker `int endOfLineIndex = sb.indexOf("\r\n");` so that I knew when to close the file. Otherwise I was always missing part of my last line.

As for deleting the whole buffer, the app was getting so slow as it was running that it seemd like a good option to prevent it from growing too big.

I am sorry for the terrible programming, but this is obviously not my forte. Would you have any recommendations to achieve the same result with a better method?